# Querying JSON data field from Oracle table

Tags: json, oracle

ORACLE:
There is a field in my "TESTREPAIR" table where one column "DETAILS" stores the following JSON.

```
{
    "repairActions": [
        {
            "symptom": 524,
            "defect": "Defective Component",
            "action": "Reflow"
        },
        {
            "symptom": 506,
            "defect": "Cosmetic",
            "action": "Repaired Component"
        },
        {
            "symptom": 509,
            "defect": "Defective Component",
            "action": "Swapped"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the SELECT statement to just query the symptoms from the above JSON data field.

Like this.

```
SELECT
    r.details.repairactions.symptom[0],
    r.details.repairactions.symptom[1],
    r.details.repairactions.symptom[2]
FROM
    testrepair r;
```

The above query is returning null. My desired output is

```
symptom1: 524
symptom2: 506
symptom3: 509
```

Comment: Just move [0] to repairaction. e.g.  r.details.repairactions[0].symptom

Comment: @Pankaj That didn't work

Comment: It should return you the value of each symptom. Are you getting an error or null?

Comment: Instead of r.details.repairactions[0].symptom I used r.details.repairActions[0].symptom and that seemed to work

Comment: :) yeah I missed the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the array index in the correct place and use quoted identifiers that match the case of the JSON:

```sql
SELECT r.details."repairActions"[0]."symptom" AS symptom1,
       r.details."repairActions"[1]."symptom" AS symptom2,
       r.details."repairActions"[2]."symptom" AS symptom3
FROM   testrepair r;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testrepair (details JSON);

INSERT INTO testrepair (details)
VALUES ('{
    "repairActions": [
        {
            "symptom": 524,
            "defect": "Defective Component",
            "action": "Reflow"
        },
        {
            "symptom": 506,
            "defect": "Cosmetic",
            "action": "Repaired Component"
        },
        {
            "symptom": 509,
            "defect": "Defective Component",
            "action": "Swapped"
        }
    ]
}');
```

Outputs:

> | SYMPTOM1 | SYMPTOM2 | SYMPTOM3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 524 | 506 | 509 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4153fd3b30b615fdf51c8df4e631e5b4)*